# Is it possible for Apache to stop proxying AJP requests in a given time period?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

We have a service configured that must go down once a week for maintenance as it is dependent on the ERP system which goes down. I'm wondering if it's possible for Apache to stop forwarding requests to Tomcat and instead serve up static content?

I imagine I could achieve this by setting up a cron job to `a2enable-site` and `a2disable-site` respectively by having a static site that gets switched out for the proxy site though I was wondering if there was a different approach I could use.

-Brett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mod_rewrite` can do rules based on the current time. Something like this untested snippet might just work:

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_WDAY} 1
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} 5
RewriteRule .* /sorry.html [L,R]
```

Comment: Dennis, this looks like exactly what I'm after. I'll have to do some experimenting, though the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) seems to suggest this is something I can do. Since every request would go through the rewrite rule, would this have any noticeable affect on performance?

Comment: That depends on your rule. Something as simple as the above shouldn't be noticeable.